# How to approach Texturing Landscape Terrains

Tags: texturing

I know this is vague but to make it specific ,
I want to know how to approach Photorealistic Landscapes in blender. Specifically the ones like on the new Open Movie Spring, if you know how they pulled it off, please give me pointers or directions. Thank you.
My goal: "From Spring Open Movie"
[image: goal]
Behind the scene of the terrain, the modeling is fairly simple and I can easily make that in Blender or Houdini "From Spring Open Movie"
[image: bts]

Comment: "*I know this is vague*" it's not vague, but it is way too broad. Why not check it out firsthand since its, you know, an OPEN movie and all. That is the whole purpose after all.

Comment: Not everyone can afford to download all the logs and scenery, that's why I'm asking. If you have seen the Behind the scene for the landscape on the OPEN movie. Then be a good timer and help me out!

Comment: Nevermind, you need to pay to subscribe to access the "OPEN" movies files.